# it there a graphic ui based svn server in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, subversive

Is there a graphic ui based svn server in ubuntu like VisualSVN Server in windows?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do. If you want a gui program to externally manage your svn repository you can try rapidsvn

```
just use the following to install: **sudo apt-get install rapidsvn** and then look in your application/programming menu for the link
```

or did you want something like rabbitsvn which integrates into a file browser?

Answer (score 0):

just install the subversion package for your ubuntu machine acting as a svn server.. command lines are powerfull for managing the svsn server.
if you want GUI, you can use the webmin tool ( You should add svnadmin module ).